# New Model Scaffolding Error in Existing project on .NET Core 6 also Not able update package reference

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

[image: The Error on Scaffolding from new Model]

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1202  Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 7.0.0-rc.1.22427.2 is not compatible with net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 7.0.0-rc.1.22427.2 supports: net7.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0) UdyogWeb    C:\Users\USER\UDYOG_PARAS\UdyogWeb\UdyogWeb.csproj  1

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild the application, and check whether the issue disappear or not? Besides, from the error message, it seems that it will use the EntityFrameworkCore 7.0, but in your application .csproj file, we can it it using the EntityFrameworkCore 6.0 version, so might be the issue relate the nuget package cache, you can try to [clear the Nuget package cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/Consume-Packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders).

Comment: Thank you for your reply but It's not solved

Comment: Hi @Monirul Islam, Does the problem solved or not? If not, there have another method you can have a try, try to re-install the relates package: such as EntityFrameworkCore. Then restart the application via Visual Studio.

Comment: No Not Solve I tried this also

Comment: Can you tell us the detail steps to reproduce the problem or it is better to create a minimal, complete sample and share it via the Github, it might be easier for us to help you fix the problem.

Comment: Yes Its basically sloved, I tried on diffect system with uninstall and install all the nuget packages and there I can use scaffolding. Thank you very much @ZhiLv